# For what values of $n$ is $(e^{i(\frac{2\pi}{3})})^n$ real?

Tags: complex-numbers

So this is my thought process:

$$
\begin{align}
(e^{i(\frac{2\pi}{3})})^n &= (e^{i(\frac{2\pi n}{3})}) \\
&= \cos{(\frac{2\pi n}{3})} + i \sin{(\frac{2\pi n}{3})} \\
\end{align}
$$

This is real when

$$
\begin{align}
\sin{(\frac{2\pi n}{3})} &= 0 \\
\frac{2\pi n}{3} &= k\pi, \; k \in \mathbb Z \\
n &= \frac{3k}{2}, \; k \in \mathbb Z \\
\end{align}
$$

But my books says that the answer is

$$n = 3k, \; k \in \mathbb Z^+$$

Which I don't understand. What am I doing wrong? (Or is the book perhaps wrong?)

Comment: In the problem statement, is $n$ required to be an integer?

Comment: Then you should restrict your $n$ to be in $\mathbb{Z}^{+}$, in which case you and the book agree.

Comment: your k must be even.

Comment: @AbdallahHammam It does seem so! However, the question is asking for the values for which it is *real*, not necessarily those for which it is real *and* positive. So wouldn't my method be correct?

Comment: @Sloan I just checked again, and it doesn't seem like it necessarily restricts $n$ to be positive (this was just meant for another part of the question): but for the course I'm learning, it is safe to assume that $n$ is an integer.